# Use template or void?

Tags: c++, templates

I need to implement a small function which does the byte swapping for an array with given length.

```
void myFunc (MYTYPE arrayPointer, const int& length)
{

unsigned int* tmp = (unsigned int*)     arrayPointer; 
for (int j=0; j < length; j = j + 4)
{
  *tmp = htonl (*(tmp));
tmp++;

}

}
```

I don't want the user to do typecasting while using the function.  I think I have two options left: 
1. Replace MYTYPE with (void*)
2. Use templates.

Which option is better or preferable? Is there any better way than these two?

Comment: Is `MYTYPE` always an `unsigned int` array?

Comment: Be careful that on some machine `htonl` don't swap anything! It depends on the native byte-ordering of your machine...

Comment: If I were writing this, I *would* require the caller to do the cast.  You're stepping four entries at a time through arrayPointer and calling a 32-bit byte swap function.

Answer (score 3):

Templates, obviously. You're going to need an `enable_if` on `sizeof(T)==4`.